# IntelliJ Idea keeps linking to library files even after creating the file again locally

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class `BaseLoginDialog` under a dependency which needs to be modified as it is not extendable out of the box. For this reason, I have created another file `BaseLoginDialog` under my project's module with the same package path as the original `BaseLoginDialog`. After adding some new methods in my own local `BaseLoginDialog`, I cannot use them anywhere in my project without IDEA complaining about the method not being declared. However, the project still compiles and the methods work fine on runtime. If I click the import to browse to the file, IntelliJ still links to the old file but it seems to correctly compile with the new one.

How can I go about fixing this issue? Always having error lines and red markers everywhere makes it confusing when coding.

Some background:
The project uses Gradle for the dependencies and compilation. Compiling and running works both with Gradle and with the IntelliJ run operation, it is only the errors being incorrectly displayed that is an issue.

The Grade file adds the required libraries as dependencies. Even though Gradle has both the source and class files, opening a file imported through Gradle still links to the class files. To get around this I also added the required files as sources under Libraries.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
Switched to use a Maven repo on the project, now I don't need to additionally add libraries anymore but this problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

The file I was copying into my local files was `BaseLoginDialog`. The file showing errors was my `NewLoginDialog` which extends `LoginDialog` which extends `BaseLoginDialog`. It seems that when IntelliJ goes to my `NewLoginDialog`, it sees that I have extended `LoginDialog`. Therefore it jumps into the library files and finds that `LoginDialog extends BaseLoginDialog`, now when it goes to find `BaseLoginDialog`, it uses the library files and ignores my local copy of `BaseLoginDialog`.

Essentially, once IntelliJ branches into a library, it does not move back out when looking for additional files if it can already find it inside the library.

To solve this issue, I simply also copied `LoginDialog` locally, even though it is identical (simply branched it and did not change anything). Now IntelliJ finds `LoginDialog` in my local files and as a result also finds `BaseLoginDialog` locally.

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If two classes of the same name and package exists in the classpath of an application, it's the one that is contained in the first dependency on the command line that gets used.

In IntelliJ, you can reorder dependencies, so you can put your local dependency before the other library. I'm not sure if that works with gradle projects, however.

But I don't think that's a good practice? Why can't you put the extra methods in a subclass, e.g. EnhancedLoginDialog, and use that one?

Or, if the original library is open source, fork it, make the changes and install it as a custom version, e.g. dialogs-1.0-CUSTOM-1.jar, and use this version in your project. And while you're at it, create a pull request for the library's maintainer to include your fixes in the next version :-)

Comment: In my project, I have <Module Source> at the top and then the rest of the Gradle libraries appear below it, this doesn't seem to solve the problem though.

And I cannot create a subclass because the class I need has been declared as final. This is an international project so requesting framework changes can take a very long time, so for this reason I have duplicated it locally for now to make sure everything works.

Comment: I've resolved this issue and posted my solution if you're interested. Thanks for the help. :)